# How to set block size with NTFS-3G

Tags: ntfs, debian

I recently wanted to increase the block size from 1Kilobyte to 16 kilobyte so I formatted it to 16KB. Unfortunately when I checked today again the following came out:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   976769023   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

So this means the block size is still at 1024Bytes -> 1KB right?

How would I increase this now in linux since formatting doesn't help..

Hope you can help :)

Comment: Are you running Debian or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The block size reported by fdisk doesn't seem to be the NTFS cluster size. I'd check the cluster size using ntfsinfo instead:

```
sudo ntfsinfo -m /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I found it:

    
        Sector Size: 512
        Cluster Size: 32768
        Index Block Size: 4096
        Volume Size in Clusters: 15261983

Comment: After all it did work :)!

Comment: @Simonski, Getting error as below. Any ideas? Access is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
You can use force option to avoid this check, but this is not recommended
and may lead to data corruption.
Failed to open '/dev/sdb1'.